# How to insert values into different tables on selection from drop down list

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to insert a value into different tables on the basis of a selected drop down list.

I have two tables first is AC and second is non-ac and i am inserting a value into a table but my (`if`) condition is not working, and data is inserting in `else` condition.

plz help me out.

```
    <select onChange="onSelect(this)" class="col-Room" name="Sroom">
     <option value="ac" >AC-Room</option>
    <option value="nonac">Non AC-Room</option>
    </select>
```

---

```
    String Room_T=" ";
    String Room[]= request.getParameterValues("Sroom");

    for(int i=0; i<Room.length; i++)
    {
        Room_T+=Room[i]+" ";

    }
```

---

```
    try
        {

                if(Room_T=="ac")
                {
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into Available_AC_Room values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    ps.setString(1,ID);
                    ps.setString(2,ACRoom);
                    ps.setString(3,Bed);
                    ps.setString(4,Bed);
                    ps.setString(5,ACDueDt);
                    ps.setString(6,RT);
                    ps.executeQuery();
                 }

                else
                {

                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into Available_NON_AC_Room values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    ps.setString(1,ID);
                    ps.setString(2,NACRoom);
                    ps.setString(3,NACBed);
                    ps.setString(4,NACBed);
                    ps.setString(5,NACDueDt);
                    ps.setString(6,ST);
                    ps.executeQuery();

                }

        }            
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.print(e);
        }
```

Comment: Could you please explain in a clearer way how you get the Room_T from the HTML dropdown? It seems to me you're losing its value somewhere (and not in your included code).

Comment: yes i forget now i given the variables where i get the value of Room_T

Comment: How do you get value of `select-box` ? Why you are using  `request.getParameterValues` to get values ? Did you have `<form>` to submit data  ? Also ,what is the use of `onChange="onSelect(this)"` ?

Comment: I Used this function for hiding rows on selection drop down list ac or non ac type this function is not related to insert data to database this is different

Comment: @ABHISHEK what does `request.getParameterValues("Sroom")` have in it ?

Comment: I am using it for getting selected values of drop down list from the jsp page to store into servlet page

Comment: You can simply get value of your dropdown using `String Room= request.getParameter("Sroom");` and then compare it by using  `if(Room.equals("ac")){ ..` . Also, i don't find any `<form>` in above code .. how are you submitting this value to your servlet?

Comment: I already applied but it did not work then i changed it..                                                                String Room= request.getParameter("Sroom");                      
   if(Room.equals("ac")){

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from:

```java
String room[]= request.getParameterValues("Sroom");

if (room != null && room.length > 0) {
    if ("ac".equals(room[0])) {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into Available_AC_room values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1,ID);
        ps.setString(2,ACroom);
        ps.setString(3,Bed);
        ps.setString(4,Bed);
        ps.setString(5,ACDueDt);
        ps.setString(6,RT);
        ps.executeQuery();
    }

    if (room.length == 1 && "nonac".equals(room[0]) || room.length == 2 && "nonac".equals(room[1])) {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into Available_NON_AC_room values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1,ID);
        ps.setString(2,NACroom);
        ps.setString(3,NACBed);
        ps.setString(4,NACBed);
        ps.setString(5,NACDueDt);
        ps.setString(6,ST);
        ps.executeQuery();
    }
}
```